# c# String.Split((string)null, , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) doesn't split on whitespace, what does it do?

Tags: c#, .net, whitespace

I had code (in this case targeting .NET Core 3.1) where I wanted to split a string on whitespace.
My draft code was

```
string s = "A B";
var parts = s.Split(null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

but the compiler complained about ambiguity between the first argument being a `(char[])` or a `(string?)`. I chose to cast the null to a string:

```
string s = "A B";
var parts = s.Split((string)null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

However, the result was unexpectedly an array of one string `"A B"`.

As it turns out, plodding through the repetitive documentation for all the overloads of Split reveals that this signature, the one that takes a single string delimiter, is the *only* one where a null delimiter does *not* mean to break on whitespace.

Had I coded `(string[])null`, `(char[])null`, `new char[0]`, or `new string[0]` I would have obtained the results I expected. I must admit that the incomplete compiler error, which failed to list all the ambiguous possibilities, somewhat led me down this wrong path. I had string delimiters on the brain and so discounted the `(char[])` version from the error message and went with the `(string)` one.

But that leaves the question, what does Split((string)null, ...) actually do? The documentation doesn't seem to say either way, but apparently the answer is that it just returns the original string in a one-element array.

Comment: null by itself is an object. The function will return the base string into a single element array if the delimiter is a null object, unless null is casted or instantiated into a string/char.

Comment: Unfortunately the MS documentation doesn't really elaborate the behavior of the separators at the different overloads. I know it's not the best answer but as I made my [`StringSegment.Split`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/Overload_KGySoft_CoreLibraries_StringSegment_Split.htm) methods functionally compatible with `String.Split` I documented the behavior quite precisely. So its corresponding [overload](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/M_KGySoft_CoreLibraries_StringSegment_Split_14.htm) mentions that for `null` or empty separator no splitting will occur.

Comment: @JosephTroy 'null by itself is an object'  this is NOT true. In c# and .NET, `null` is nothing, nada, zilch, nothing, not an object.

Comment: @PeterB Yes, you are correct.  Null is not an object... it's the absence of an object.  so, in all, the function doesn't know what to do with a null delimiter, thus returning the input string (in a single element array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken directly from the source code for .Net Standard 2.1, which includes .Net Core 3.1, the definition of `Split(string? separator, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)`, at [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs,9c9fb345e3939b63):

```
public string[] Split(string? separator, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
{
    return SplitInternal(separator ?? string.Empty, null, int.MaxValue, options);
}
```

As you can see, it checks for `null` and passes `string.Empty` to the method `SplitInternal`, so to answer your question, it splits on an empty string, which produces the original string.

These produce the same results:

```
string s = "Hello World";   
Console.WriteLine(s.Split((string)null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]); //prints Hello World
Console.WriteLine(s.Split(string.Empty, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]); //prints Hello World
```

Comment: The behaviour of String.Split(String.Empty, ...) is also poorly documented. In the version that takes an array of strings, it is explicitly stated that null or empty strings in the array are ignored, but there is no such advice for the version that takes a single string.

Comment: Further examination of the source code verifies that SplitInternal(String.Empty, ...) does indeed yield a 1-element array containing the target string. An alternative interpretation could have been that the empty string is found between each character in the original string, yielding an array of 1-character strings, though this interpretation would have been problematic if empty strings were requested since there are an infinite number of such empty strings between each character in the input string!